# IIS 7.5 - 403 Forbidden

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, iis-7.5

Ok, I have scoured online resources and applied all the suggested solutions.

I am setting up a simple website on Windows Server 2008 R2 under IIS 7.5 using the "ASP.NET v4.0" pool. I am setting this up as an application under Default Web Site with a different root. I keep getting the 403 Forbidden error.

I have:

1. Installed asp.net using aspnet_regiis.exe -i (many times)
2. Made sure my root directory (physical path) has permissions for
   "IIS_IUSR" and "IUSR" users.
3. Made sure "Anonymous Authentication" is enabled and set to "Application Pool Identity"
4. I have restarted IIS numerous times
5. I have checked and double-checked every other configuration.

What's strange is that I have another application under Default Web Site and it works just fine.

Any suggestions will help. This shouldn't be so hard unless I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: I disagree.  IIS is a programming tool, and ServerFault does not help for anything programming related like configuring IIS for an app that is being programmed.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ok, I am quite embarrassed but the over sight was that "Require SSL" was checked by default and that is the place I did not check. I guess it is because an SSL is bound to the Default Web Site. Removing that check made it work.

Hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: I came to a similar problem and noticed the same port was in use for a different matter

Comment: What if you want require https checked?  I have a site which has a redirect attribute filter and I want it to always be https

Comment: After trying everything I checked the SSL settings and I had the same requirement set. D'oh!

Answer (score 25):

Haha you think that is embarrasing!  This is probably the 1000th webserver I've installed...  30mins of 403s!!  I can't figure it out.  There is a stub default.asp in there.. permissions all correct... everything!

I turned on "directory" browsing in desparation of flicking around.

`default.asp.txt` is sitting there.....  DOH.

Need to turn OFF "known file types"... why is that setting like that anyway?

Comment: Yes, those hidden file types be darned.

Comment: This answer just saved me hours of lost time trying to find the source of the problem. Thanks

Comment: I have no idea why that option is enabled even on windows data center 2016

Comment: Dude... wow. Saved my life man!  Every... Freaking... Time... I am working on a new windows machine.

Comment: I was about to downvote this answer, as this is more a comment than a real answer. But, man... you've just saved my day...

Comment: That is the first thing I turn off when I install any Windows OS on a new machine or a new AMI

Comment: Just swinging by to say.... yup, this was me today. New server, setting up placeholder site, hadn't checked "View File Extensions" yet. +1

Comment: This is exactly it right here and needs a thousand up votes.  I wish the answer was given more directly to catch the attention.

Answer (score 9):

Another possible issue which leads to a 403 error:

The `Global.asax` file is missing.

Answer (score 7):

For me the answer was in handler mappings section of IIS 7.5

Adding the following to web.config enabled all the aspx pages to work correctly

```
<configuration>
...
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script" />
    ... 
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

Grant permission to the `Network Service` user in the NTFS folder

Also check the .Net authorization rules:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have specified the app pool user as "ApplicationPoolIdentity" which is a virtual user in my case like "IIS AppPool\ASP.NET v4.0". Therefore, Network Service user permissions should not matter. Plus IIS_IUSR includes all app pool users. The authorization rules are fine.

Comment: The screencap is so small that I'm not really even sure what menu this is.

Answer (score 1):

Check that IP address restrictions are not blocking the request.  Can check this in the logs.

(This was my embarrassing reason!)

Answer (score 1):

Mine was even more embarrassing.

Right Click on folder,`Remove READ only attribute`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, there was a vestigial `Web.config` in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` with rewrite rules. Deleting it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing issue on windows 7 and surprisingly it was fixed after installing service pack 1

Answer (score 0):

You might also get this if setting up FTP for a website and you try and change the default directory for FTP on the website.

From what I can tell:

Manage FTP Site -> Advanced Settings -> Physical Path

is the same

Manage Website -> Advanced Settings -> Physical Path

Changing one will change the other and possibly cause a 403 on a working site.