# Access to application was denied You don't have authorisation to view this page. HTTP ERROR 403

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7.5, shared-hosting

I have a shared hosting environment which supports asp.net 4.0 with IIS 7.5.
We had developed application in .net framework 4.5.2 with asp.net mvc 5.0.0.0.
As i had deployed application through ftp and when i had navigated through site url then i was getting message like "Access to site was denied.You don't have authorisation to view this page.HTTP ERROR 403".
I had tried many solutions from stack overflow as follows : 
 1. 
 2. had given full permission to root folder (network service)
 3. Enable/disable directory browsing history
None of them was working at my end.
Once i may remove all content and put a simple html page then it will work.
Is there anything that i forgot to add or miss?

I had followed "[403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805311/403-forbidden-access-is-denied-asp-net-mvc)", "[IIS 7.5 - 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111911/iis-7-5-403-forbidden)"

Comment: Have you deploy your site correctly? Have you setup your own default page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got a solution for this issue.
As my application was built in ASP.Net MVC 5 and it needs full trust level. 
We have a shared hosting where full trust level is not allowed so we had converted our application to MVC 4 and tried to deploy it on same server and it worked.
I also reviewed that Microsoft stopped support for medium trust for upgraded version of ASP.Net MVC.
We eventually knew this issue by reaching at hosting provider as some hosting provider supports MVC 5 application but some can not.